# Mission Control app switching is broken - chosen app is NOT focused

Tags: mission-control, multitasking, expose

Problem:

1. Activate mission control
2. Chose app - eg. Click Safari
3. Mission control exit animation plays, but an app OTHER than Safari has focus.

I cannot express how frustrating this is. There is another (possibly related) issue also occuring: if I have an app eg. Chrome on a full-screen space, selecting that space will focus it, but another Chrome window from my desktop will then appear in focus, on top of the full-screen Chrome space.

Might help for context:
[macOS Sierra lost focus Finder when using mission controls](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257047/macos-sierra-lost-focus-finder-when-using-mission-controls)

Comment: Spaces only works when an app is in only one single Space. If you spread it to more than one Space, the behaviour will be inconsistent.